# How can I inherit the docstring of the class in my constructor

Tags: c#, docstring, code-documentation

I have a class to generate test data that I have documented with a docstring.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// In this scenario the user is new to the group, but may have existed from before.
/// </summary>
class NewUserData {
    public User user;
    // More data fields here ...

    public NewUserData(){ 
        // Creating test data here ...
    }
}
```

The class is used in a unit test like this:

```cs
var data = new NewUserData();
```

Hovering over `NewUserData` doesn't show me the docstring in IDE (Visual Studio). Is there a way to make this happen without moving the docstring down to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Found out one can achieve this with the inheritdoc tag and specify the class name as cref.

```cs
/// <inheritdoc cref="NewUserData"/>
var data = new NewUserData();
```